# My app icon appears smaller then other

Tags: android, android-icons

I used android asset studio to create Launcher icon:

> http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-launcher.html#foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=33b5e5%2C0&crop=0&backgroundShape=bevel&backColor=ffffff%2C100

The studio generated images at proper pixel sizes: 48 * 48 (mdpi) 72 *72 (hdpi) and so on..

But on my Samsung galaxy s2 the app icon appear smaller then other apps and not filling its entire space.

Whay is this? how can i stretch it to full extent?

Comment: When you open it in a graphics editor, do you see it filling the whole image? Does it have transparent area around it?

Comment: Perhaps you put them into the wrong folders when you were copying them over?  I had seen this happen to me before, I just don't recall what the cause was.

Comment: In my case, yes, there is a transparent border around the icon, but couldn't figure out how to prevent this with android asset studio.

Answer (score 5):

Asset studio adds unnecessary margins to the icon.  If someone can come up with a similar tool without adding margins, it would be of great help.  The solution to your problem is to use a single 512 by 512 image as icon.  Android will scale the rest for you when users install your app.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of importing image through `Image Asset` in Android Studio, make 5 images with different size:

- 48 x 48
- 72 x 72
- 96 x 96
- 144 x 144
- 192 x 192

And then directly copy in respective `Drawable` folder (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi) with same name.

Comment: Problem persist even after doing what you said

Comment: This works! @LeonardoDaCodinchi you probably did not copy the respective icons to the mipmap folder!

Comment: I know im late to the party but, this worked for me and should be the selected answer or at least the more voted one (not the "just add 512X512 and let the magic happen...", which did not worked)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with the Asset Studio on Android Studio.
The only work-around was to make the images myself. Most of the time, just providing one image at 192*192 worked for me, instead of creating the whole mipmap.

Answer (score 0):

Check the drawable-hdpi folder, and see if it has the correct one. The SII has a HDPI density, so you might have copied the icon into the wrong folder.

Source: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/

Answer (score 0):

Finding myself in the same situation, I generated the so called web icon, which gave me the rounded corners and shadow and the size big enough to remove padding and produce all the required sizes myself in a graphic editor.

Answer (score 0):

Put a 512 * 512 icon in **drawable folder** instead of **mipmap** and then from Android Manifest reference it through android:icon tag

> android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"

Worked for me, no margin on corners.